# Transparency falloff for volume (clouds)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

I am using volume shader to create clouds, however I would like the clouds to fade into the background near the horizon, but be opaque higher up in the cloudhead. Is there any way to set a vertical falloff for transparency with a volume shader? Here is a real life image to demonstrate the look I want to achieve. You will not towards the horizon the clouds fade into the color of the sky[image]

Comment: Does mist not work in this scenario?

Comment: Hello :). A simple Z axis gradient plugged into Volume Density should work.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard yes mist is one option I considered using for part of the effect. From what I understand this requires using the compositor, right? That is fine, it is just not visible when arranging the scene in the 3d editor. Also, it is depth based and I am looking for something that is more height based. In the pic above youre right it does seem to be more of a depth-based effect but what I am aiming for it more of a height based effect.

Comment: @Jachym Michal thank you! I will have to play around with that option. The cloud effect I am working with is pretty complicated and uitilizes multiple types of shaders so I will post again if I run into specific questions when trying this. I know my clouds use a shader to rgb node which I am concerned will interfere with what I am trying to achieve...